# Using PHP for email file in HTML

Tags: php, html

I've been having problems using php in my html form. While it will send, the $_POST variables are empty when I try to grab them in the php file. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

My HTML code:

```html
<form class="submitAMessage" name="Submit a Message" method="post" action="sendresults.php">
  <div>
    <h4>Submit a Message:</h4>
    <label for="name">Name:<br><span class="required"></span></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div> <br>
    <label for="email">Email Address:<br><span class="required"></span></label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div> <br>
    <label for="message">Message:<br><span class="required"></span></label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here." required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" formmethod="POST" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

My php file:

```
<?php
//--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

// Subject of email sent to you.
$subject = 'Results from Contact Form';

$emailfrom = 'noreply@website.com';

// Your email address. This is where the form information will be sent. 
$emailadd = 'website@gmail.com'; 

// Where to redirect after form is processed. 
$url = 'http://www.website.com/main.html'; 

// Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty.
// If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
$req = '0'; 

// --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
$text = "Results from Form:\n\n";
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$line = '
';

mail($emailadd, $subject, $text.$name.$line.$email.$line.$message, 'From: '.$emailfrom.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

The only thing that sends in the email is:

```
Results from Form:
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a framework/library like PHPMail or Rmail.  You have to send the correct headers for it to be seen as html, which is a real pain to do manually.

Comment: That said you might be mixing line endings if this is written on a windows computer ( "\r\n" ) you have `$line = ' '` and `$text = "blah\n";` try `$line="\n"`.  If that is not the case then email and message are empty....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the headers into the mail function which is option.

Here is the functions all parameters

**bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )**

> **$to** Receiver, or receivers of the mail.
>
> **$subject** Subject of the email to be sent.
>
> **$message** Message to be sent.
>
> **$additional_headers** this is the optional headers which is used for the mail options

you can to set the following values in headers.

```
// header configuration for to send the HTML mail
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

> **$additional_parameters** The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass additional flags as command line options to the program configured to be used when sending mail

Answer (score 0):

You should use the header in mail function. Add following code in in your code too.

```
 $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
 $header .= "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($emailadd, $subject, $text.$name.$line.$email.$line.$message,$header, 'From: '.$emailfrom.'');
```

Good luck.